# When Did Raja VikramAditya Do Parkaya Pravesh

Tags: vikramaditya

I’ve googled this several times and couldn’t find accurate info, does anyone know when Raja VikramAditya did parkaya pravesh ?

He was a Hindu bhakt types and a good king who did everything to helped his people, so must’ve done for some good purpose.

Comment: Many kings have held the title Vikramāditya, don't know who you are talking about. Also, there are many legends, poems and literary works such as *Vetāla Pañcaviṃśati* associated to Vikramāditya. The legendary Vikramāditya from Vetāla stories is historically considered to have been inspired from many kings by different scholars, some considered him to be inspired from Chandragupta II, or Skandagupta, or Yaśodharman and so on.

Comment: @Bingming Thx, yea I know it’s a title like Indra or any other position, & there is a particular story of VikramAditya performing parkaya pravesh that I was wondering about, so posted this question. I can’t recall if it’s part of the Vikram Betaal stories w/ the 32 steps, I remember liking those stories very much though. If it’s not a good question I can just delete it later, I’ve deleted many of my own idiotic questions on here hehe:D  But yeah there’s a well known parkaya pravesh story w/ Raja VikramAditya that I’d like to know more about if anyone might has info on that 

Comment: I see, you can share that story or its source, that would make the question better I guess

Comment: @Bingming I’m googling further for the source, not coming up w/ much so far, can’t remember the story details. If come up w/ more info I’ll edit the question so it’s not so vague. Thx though, I appreciate you taking the time to comment 

Comment: Raja Vikramāditya is most probably Chandragupta ll. As far as i recall the most famous stories about him included Vetāla Pañcaviṃśati (Vikram-Vetal) and Singhāsana Battisi (32 stories related to his throne). In those legends he is said to be the son of Jayanta and the grandson of Lord Indra himself. So, you can search those stories or see their animations or anything...

Comment: @Savdy Thx ! I’m checking but didn’t find the exact story yet. I keep looking 

Comment: @devibhakt u r welcome. Sometimes it happens just we don't remember the right key words for google search. So, just keep on searching with different but similar words. Bdw, Happy New Year to you n ur family. Cya. Tc. ..